# Outputting files from Mapping Data Flow in defined hierarchy is slow

Tags: azure-data-factory

When using Data Factory to transform data and output with a set filename and path pattern, performance doesn't meet expectations. The main performance bottleneck appears to be the way files are written. Azure Data Lake Storage (Gen 2) is being used in this instance.

The transformation is being done via a Mapping Data Flow. A sink filename is being generated via a Derived Column activity, which is then used in the sink (Delimited Text) with 'File name option' set to 'As data in column' and the field is selected.

From what I've observed, when the pipeline runs the files are written to a temporary location then moved to the intended target location.

```
[Temp location]
- GUID
  - SinkFilename=<escaped full target path>

[Final destination]
- GUID
  - Year
    - Month
      - Data.csv
```

It's the second part of this process that seems very slow where only 5 or so files were being moved per second. When there are thousands of files being output it's unsuitably slow.

Documentation for [data flow performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance#file-name-options) details the overhead of this 'shuffle' process, but doesn't provide guidance on any alternate approach. If have seen an example where partitioning was set to key columns which was then reflected in the folder hierarchy as `Year=2020/Month=05/<generated file names>` which wasn't optimal from an output perspective.

What is the best approach to maintaining performance while outputting files in a defined structure for other systems to comsume?

Comment: The alternative approach is to allow data flows to maintain spark partitioning and output the partitioned files without requiring the secondary step of merging/renaming those files, i.e. use default/current naming and partitioning. Then, add another activity in your pipeline after this primary data flow that renames or merges those files.

Comment: @MarkKromerMSFT You've given a good overview of output options in [Output Format in ADF Data Flows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NAPSbjvSQA8). I struggle with what the rename and merge process would look like in Data Factory, if not another Mapping Data Flow. Perhaps a combination of Get-Metadata/For-Each/Copy-Data, but there seems to be a lack of metadata (filename pattern or attributes) on data output by the first process. Any guidance you could provide on that aspect?

Comment: You can use Merge Files option in Copy Activity or use another Data Flow. In both cases, your source would use either the entire folder as a source or a wildcard so that all files are accumulated. Then, your output will be a new single file either from the Copy Activity dataset or the Data Flow "write to single file option".